# Jquery Functions for operations on gridview with checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

The first column in my gridview (gvAvailable) is a currently checkbox column "chkSelect".
The way it works now is that a user can check multiple checkboxes on a gridview, but I would like a jquery function to deselect all the checkboxes on the gridview except for the checkbox that was clicked.

I was also looking for a way to access the columns of the checked row with jquery on a button click.

Thanks for any help

Here's how the generated html looks

```
<table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="gvAvailable" style="width:99%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr class="GridHeader">
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Guid</th><th scope="col">Id</th><th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Facility</th><th scope="col">Room</th>
</tr>
<tr class="GridItem">
    <td>
        <input id="gvAvailable_ctl02_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="gvAvailable$ctl02$chkSelect" />
    </td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>000101020201</td>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test Facility</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr class="GridAltItem">
<td>
    <input id="gvAvailable_ctl03_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="gvAvailable$ctl03$chkSelect" />
</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>1001</td>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td>Test 3</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the generated HTML? I know jQuery but I am not a .NET guy so I have no idea what a gridview is or what it may show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add the same class to each of the checkboxes in the markup, you can retrieve an array of them by saying

```
$('.classname')
```

This will give you back the array of objects. You can then call 'each' on the array and deselect them all.

```
function removeChecks()
{    
    $('.classname').each(function()
    {
         $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
}
```

Then add the above function call in the click handler for the each checkbox:

```
$('.classname').each(function()
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        removeChecks();
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

the code above should be set up to run on page load.

Comment: Thanks paintball.
Do you know of a method i can use to access that checked rows columns on a button click event?

Comment: in jquery you can access the elements parent rather easily, as well as an element's siblings in the DOM tree. To access an array of all the <td> elements in the same <tr>, you can select the checkbox's parent's siblings. The code:

$('checkbox').parent().siblings()

will return an array of the <td> elements in the same row as checkbox. From there you can do whatever you want to those elements.

Answer (score 2):

In this example I put one button to check, and one button to uncheck gridview checkboxes :

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grid"></asp:GridView>

<input type="button" onclick="uncheckCheckBoxes()" value="UnCheck" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" onclick="checkCheckBoxes()" value="Check" />

<script>
    function uncheckCheckBoxes()
    {
        var gridClientID = '<%= grid.ClientID %>';
        jQuery.each($("#" + gridClientID + " input[type='checkbox']"), function ()
        {
          this.checked = false;
        });
    }

    function checkCheckBoxes()
    {
        var gridClientID = '<%= grid.ClientID %>';
        jQuery.each($("#" + gridClientID + " input[type='checkbox']"), function ()
        {
          this.checked = true;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you would like to make sure the user clicked checkboxes do not get toggled?  If so, go on below.

First, just give a class name to all checkboxes in the gridview.

Whenever a checkbox was clicked, add another class to it to denote it was physically selected.

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('checked');
});
```

Now, when a user clicks on the select all checkbox (let's call it "selectAll") on top, iterate through all the checkboxes and toggle the status while checking the "checked" class

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(){
   var status = $(this).attr('checked')
   $('.checkbox').each(function(){
      //only toggle if not set
      if(!$(this).hasClass('checked')){
        if(status){
          $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        else{
          $(this).attr('checked', '');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

This should get you along your merry way hopefully.

Now, accessing columns of the checked row?

```
You could add an onclick event to each table row.
$('#tablename tr').click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

Comment: I've tried using this but for some reason nothing is happening.
i changed my checkbox control class to "checked" and added those two functions in, but It still allows me select multiple checkboxes in a gridview

Answer (score 0):

i found [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=236) articale very usefull Check/Uncheck all Items in an ASP.NET CheckBox List using jQuery